# Is it possible to import Azure DevOps pipeline reports to Power BI?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

Checking guidance of Pipeline reports at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/reports/pipelinereport?view=azure-devops

Curious if it's possible to create a power bi report and import the  Azure DevOps pipeline analysis report (for example, the Pipeline duration)?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DVD How was it going with this case? Was below steps helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve this. You may have to get the data by calling Azure devops rest api from power Bi to get the builds infomation and then try to deal with the time data retrieved from azure devops.

1, To get the build info data in PowerBi.

Click **Get Data** and then choose **From Web**. Then enter the below [build restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and configure the Authorization header parameter

```
 https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&api-version=5.1
```

For the authorization header, you need first to get a [Person access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). And use below powershell script to convert it to base64string format

```
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(Person access token)"))
```

After you get the base64string format PAT, you can use the basic authorization to retrieve the build info from azure devops.

[image]

To process the build info retrieved by above restful api is a hard task. There are three properties **queueTime**, **startTime**, And **finishTime** that you can use to construct your power bi report. I donot know much about powerbi, you have to find a way to deal with **startTime** and **finishTime** to calculate the duration time, For there is not a build duration property of the returned build.

Hope you find above hopeful.

Comment: what if i want to import a powerscript file of a pipeline from azure devops? what should be the api?